# What would be the most appropriate measure I should take if I feel that I am failing to submit my MSc thesis within deadline?

Tags: thesis, masters

In February-2016, I have undertaken my thesis. That was the topic proposed by my supervisor on my request. I started to work on the project and finding that I am actually short of various topics/knowledge(theoretical and practical). I still contacted the supervisor and he passed me in my lab and told me to continue the work.

The last date of my thesis submission is 2016–09–15.

I have been started to have a feeling that I wouldn’t be able to complete the thesis. Coz, my previous knowledge is not sufficient to complete the lab-project and hence the thesis.

What would be the consequence if I am unable to submit the thesis?

What would be the most appropriate measure I should take to save my thesis/career/semester/grade and so on?

Comment: Work harder and request for an extension of the deadline. That's pretty much all there is to it.

Comment: **Talk to your advisor.  Today.**

Comment: @JeffE, **OK. Should I tell him everything?**

Comment: Yes; you should.

Answer (score 3):

The key question that you need to answer is "why".

If there are serious, unforeseeable circumstances that have effected your ability to progress with your research and/or submit on time (such as illness),  then you should refer to your institution's policy and guidance on applying for an extension, mitigating circumstances etc.  Hopefully these will be considered and you will be granted an extension or a late submission will be accepted without penalty.

Some institutions also accept work-related circumstances as mitigating.

If it's down to poor planning, failing to adhere to your supervisor's advice or meet key milestones, bad luck etc, then, alas, it's unlikely that you will be granted any kind of dispensation to submit late.  Nonetheless, I'd advise you contact your supervisor to let them know the situation in the hope that they will help you unpick the situation.

In all circumstances, I'd suggest you talk to your supervisor as soon as possible or another adviser who might be able to help.

EDIT: Let this be a lesson to future readers - always ask for help sooner rather than later if you find yourself running into trouble and fear missing a deadline.  Two weeks before due date isn't going to cut it.

Comment: In February-2016, I have undertaken my thesis. That was the topic proposed by my supervisor on my request. I started to work on the project and finding that I am actually short of various topics/knowledge(theoretical and practical). I still contacted the supervisor and he passed me in my lab and told me to continue the work.

Comment: I sympathize with your situation, there is too much scope for students to get a raw deal with the supervisor they are assigned.  Although, didn't you have any tutorials with your supervisor?  If not, then they're not much of a supervisor, in which case I would bring this to the attention of one of the department administrators (assuming that they have not fulfilled the duties required of their role).

Answer (score 1):

I just finished my master thesis. Let me put in my two cents.

Usually the first thing you should do is to talk to your supervisor. Before the commencement of supervision there is usually a signed contract that ensures supervisors to commit to supervise you and help you finish your thesis before the deadline. He has responsibility to help you. Of course, you should still take the responsibility to try your best and communicate with your supervisor because it is your thesis.

I met the same situation two months before my deadline, and fortunately my supervisor crafted the research topic broad enough, so I can lower my goals and still fulfill the requirement of the initial project proposal. Certainly it made me a little bit frustrated.

Secondly, if you can't finish your thesis on time due to some pardonable reasons, you usually can extend the deadline for a few more weeks. (check the regulation in your department)

In the worst scenario when you failed to communicate with your supervisor, there is usually a proof reader who you can turn to, or you can report to the committee board of your department to intervene the case.